# Overlay browser preferences from firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to add a overlay to the preferences of the browser from my extension without success. Nothing is displayed when my plugin is installed. Other xul files show correctly (for example a preferences dialog of the plugin. I tried to adapt [this](http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/prefs) tutorial to my needs.

I register the overlay in chrome.manifest:

```
content smime chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/preferences/preferences.xul chrome://smime/content/preferences.xul
```

The preferences.xul:

```
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<!-- Merge with the BrowserPreferences Window -->
<prefwindow id="BrowserPreferences">

  <!-- Create a new pane (tab) for HP Scheduler. -->
  <prefpane id="hpschedPane" label="&prefpane.label;"
            image="chrome://smime/content/sogo-48.png">

    <!-- Intermediary between GUI and preferences system -->
    <preferences>
    <preference id="sodgeItSmimeKeyfile" name="extensions.sodgeItSmime.keyfile" type="text"/>

    </preferences>
    <!-- GUI Elements... -->
    <groupbox>
        <caption label="Settings"/>
        <grid>
            <columns>
                <column flex="4"/>

                <column flex="1"/>
            </columns>
            <rows>
                <row>
                    <label control="keyfile" value="Keyfile"/>
                    <textbox id="keyfile" preference="sodgeItSmimeKeyfile"/>

                </row>
            </rows>
        </grid>
    </groupbox>
    </prefpane>
</prefwindow>
</overlay>
```

This is what I want to do - add a tab in the Firefox settings dialog.

[image]

Edit: added image to describe what I'm trying to do

Comment: Is this the one?? [url=http://postimage.org/image/l7jopntxz/][img]http://s15.postimage.org/l7jopntxz/Firefox.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: edited the question and added a image with what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trickier to get this to work than it should be. You might try the following approach, which we use in our FireTorrent extension:

1. Overlay the Firefox preference window as shown:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://firetorrent/skin/firetorrent-prefs.css" type="text/css"?>

   <overlay id="FiretorrentPaneOverlay"
       xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

       <prefwindow id="BrowserPreferences">
           <prefpane id="paneFiretorrent" label="FireTorrent"
               src="chrome://firetorrent/content/optionsOverlay.xul"/>
       </prefwindow>
   </overlay>
   ```
2. Add the following to your CSS file (`firetorrent-prefs.css` in the example):

   ```
   #BrowserPreferences radio[pane="paneFiretorrent"] {
     list-style-image: url("chrome://firetorrent/skin/firetorrent-icon-32.png");
   }
   ```
3. Contents of `optionsOverlay.xul` as follows:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/preferences.css" type="text/css"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://firetorrent/skin/options.css" type="text/css"?>

   <!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://firetorrent/locale/optionsOverlay.dtd">

   <overlay id="firetorrentOptionsOverlay"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

       <prefpane id="paneFiretorrent" onpaneload="loadOptions();" flex="1">

           <preferences>
               <preference id="firetorrent.options.port" name="extensions.firetorrent.port" type="int"/>
               ...etc...
           </preferences>

           <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://firetorrent/content/optionsOverlay.js"/>

           ...all your prefpane XUL here...
       </prefpane>
   </overlay>
   ```

It's been a long time since I wrote this, but I believe the important things to note are that the overlay for `preferences.xul` (point 1 in my example) references another XUL overlay that contains the actual prefpane (`optionsOverlay.xul`) and that you need to use the `list-style-image` style in CSS to specify the icon for your new tab.